# GPIB to USB adaptor differences

Tags: gpib

I have an old device that can only communicate via GPIB, so I have to buy a GPIB to USB adaptor that will allow me to send commands using the VISA library.

However I have seen that the price can vary dramatically between adaptors.

- An AK40G GPIB to USB adaptor costs around 250 EUR
- A Keysight adaptor costs around 680 EUR
- A Keithley adaptor costs around 1000 EUR
- A National Instruments cost around 1500 EUR

I understand that prices can vary between different companies, but here we are talking about huge difference in price.

Is there any functional difference between this adaptors? What is the reason for such a big difference in price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main differences are drivers and support. The Keysight, Keithley and NI adapters are guaranteed to work with VISA. I don't know about the AK40G.

There are also Arduino based open source adapters out there - these might appear as a GPIB adapter in the device manager, a TM (Test & measurement device) or as a serial port, depends on the driver implementation.